# Can't define fixed-width font with TexShop, fontspec

Tags: fonts, code

I've used [Alex Hirzel's code](https://gist.github.com/3477384) to enable code snippets in LaTex articles:

[image]

The problem is that I can't set the font to a fixed-width one. Whenever this line is commented out:

```
%\fontspec{Courier New}
```

I get the following error:

```
./code3.tex:33: Undefined control sequence.
\codefont -> \fontspec 
                       {Courier New} \fontsize {9pt}{11pt}\selectfont 
l.33 \begin{code}
```

Any idea how can I set the font type? I'm using TexShop on Mac, if it matters.

Comment: Load the `fontspec` package (and naturally compile then with `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the `fontspec` package (and naturally compile then with `xelatex` or `lualatex`).